# How to use os.Open()'s return value as the third parameter of http.Post() and set Content-Length?

Tags: file-upload, go

The third parameter of `http.Post()` allows `io.Reader` and that means the return value of `os.Open()` should work. But the below code gets unexpected result, in other words, it won't set `Content-Length` properly. Perhaps `File` type doesn't implement something. Is there any proper way to set `Content-Length` with `*File`?

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "os"
)

var sample = []byte(`hello`)

func main() {
    ts := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        log.Println(r.Header)
        if int(r.ContentLength) != len(sample) {
            log.Fatal("Unexpected Content-Length:", r.ContentLength)
        }
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        w.Write([]byte(`{}`))
    }))
    defer ts.Close()

    file, err := ioutil.TempFile(os.TempDir(), "")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer os.Remove(file.Name())
    file.Write(sample)

    // This works
    buf, err := ioutil.ReadFile(file.Name())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    _, err = http.Post(ts.URL, "application/octet-stream", bytes.NewBuffer(buf))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // This looks fine in my opinion, though it doesn't set Content-Length
    f, err := os.Open(file.Name())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    _, err = http.Post(ts.URL, "application/octet-stream", f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 map[Content-Type:[application/octet-stream] Accept-Encoding:[gzip] User-Agent:[Go-http-client/1.1] Content-Length:[5]]
2009/11/10 23:00:00 map[Content-Type:[application/octet-stream] Accept-Encoding:[gzip] User-Agent:[Go-http-client/1.1]]
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Unexpected Content-Length:-1
```

https://play.golang.org/p/hJLN2H9Y9p

Comment: Why do you need to set Content-Length?

Comment: A web application built with Flask (python) has `request.stream` and it didn't work without sending Content-Length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at source for [NewRequest](https://golang.org/src/net/http/request.go#L598) you can see that contentLength is handled specially for specific input types, and the file reader isn't one of them. You'll have to manually set the Content-Length header if that's important [chunked should also work fine, unless you're sending to an old server impl].

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a add the `Content-Length`, you need to stat the file to get the size. The ContentLength isn't calculated automatically because an `os.File` may not have a useful size.

```
f, err := os.Open(file.Name())
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", ts.URL, f)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

stat, err := f.Stat()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

req.ContentLength = stat.Size()
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")

resp, err = http.Do(req)
...
```